# iOS Facebook SDK 3.5 publication. App name is not displayed (posts published via "iOS")

Tags: facebook, ios6

I want to make facebook publication on the iOS6. The way I do it:

1. Ask for read permission
2. Ask for publish permission
3. Call [FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialog...]

It works but in feed I see "via iOS" and I want to see my app name instead. How can it be fixed? If I make publications with Feed Dialog (web based) - my application name is displayed correct

```
- (IBAction)facebookShareButtonTaped:(id)sender
{
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
    {
        if (status == FBSessionStateOpen)
        {
            [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                [self sendFacebookPost];
            }];
        }
    }];
}

- (BOOL)sendFacebookPost
{
    BOOL dialogShown = [FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:self initialText:@"" image:nil url:nil handler:^(FBOSIntegratedShareDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
        if (error && [error code] == 7)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (error)
        {
            [self showAlert:[self checkErrorMessage:error]];
        }
        else if (result == FBNativeDialogResultSucceeded)
        {
            [self showAlert:@"Posted successfully."];
        }
    }];

    return dialogShown;
}
```

Comment: were you able to figure this one out? i am facing the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately I were not

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name that should show up by adding a new entry to the Information Property List within your plist file. Just add the key `FacebookDisplayName` with the name you want as its value.